# What is the best way to establish connection between ASP.net and Salesforce

Tags: integration, .net

I am trying to have an ASP.net application to use a salesforce data. What is the best way to establish connection?

What are the options available?

1. oauth
2. webservices
3. connectionstrings in asp.net ?
4. API?

What is the best or the most common way of establishing this connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic approaches you could take for this endeavor: (1) REST via OAuth, or (2) Web Services via SOAP. The "API" traditionally refers to the SOAP API, which is synonymous with "web services."

Go with REST if you want a snappy, responsive site that doesn't upload much data at once (the REST API isn't well-suited for bulk uploads), or the SOAP API for a fully-featured API with more power. There's other options, too, but they basically fall in one of those two categories.

The major factor here relies on complexity versus functionality. If you're more familiar with WSDL files, and that makes you feel all happy inside, by all means, go for it. If you prefer a lighter JSON or XML payload, then REST can come to your rescue. Neither method is definitively superior, although JSON has an edge because of the more compact protocol (usually at least half as much bandwidth as SOAP).

It's also possible to mix and match. A SOAP session ID can be used in REST, and a REST token can be a SOAP session ID. Given that the functionality of the APIs are essentially the same, you should simply take into consideration the skill fo the developer(s), and the familiarity with various protocols such as SOAP or JSON.